# How to uninstall all but the default Ubuntu packages?

Tags: package-management

I have a Dell Mini 9 with a 8 GB SSD. I installed Lucid some years ago, and upgraded each time, and now my hard disk is almost full. I see that new default programs get installed but old ones do not get automatically removed (e.g. Banshee and Rhythmbox). Now I can install a new distro from scratch but if there is a way to avoid the hassle, it would be great. I don't mind if the programs I have installed over the years get removed, they are only a few and I can reinstall them in a snap.

Comment: I think this can help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/33907/cleaning-disc-space

Comment: My best bet would be somehow purging all installed packages and then install `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage. The reason this is a comment is because I don't know how to specify all packages, but if you are able to delete them, and install `ubuntu-desktop` you will land with the default install of your current Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [solution to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39633/where-can-i-find-a-complete-list-of-packages-that-are-installed-by-default-in-ubu/39638#39638) will probably solve your problem too.

#### Ubuntu pre-12.04

From a `gnome-terminal` do:

```
cat filesystem.manifest-desktop | awk '{print $1}' | sort > default.txt
```

This will get rid of the package versions and leave you with a sorted list *default.txt* containing all packages that are installed by default. As mentioned in the linked question, keep in mind that you might changed the default installation when installing updates and/or restricted packages during the installation of Ubuntu.

#### Ubuntu 12.04

The above step has changed a bit. To get a list of the packages that are initially installed, you need to unpack two files:

1. *filesystem.manifest*
2. *filesystem.manifest-remove*

To get what you want, you need to remove the latter from the former:

```
comm -3 <(cat filesystem.manifest | awk '{print $1}' | sort) <(cat filesystem.manifest-remove | sort) > default.txt
```

Now continue like pre-12.04:

```
dpkg --get-selections | awk '{print $1}' | sort > current.txt
```

This will get you a sorted list *current.txt* of all currently installed packages.

```
diff -u default.txt current.txt | grep "^+[^+]" | cut -c 2- > installed.txt
diff -u default.txt current.txt | grep "^-[^-]" | cut -c 2- > uninstalled.txt
```

This will get you the differences between the two package lists, where *installed.txt* contains all packages not part of the default installation, and *uninstalled.txt* contains all packages you are missing compared to a default installation.

Comment: Thanks but I think I have created a dependency soup, I will go with the installation from scratch. Your method seems to work though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this helped me a bunch! FYI for future users: filesystem.manifest-desktop can be found on the Ubuntu CD under the casper/ folder. Other than that this worked perfectly, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on removing those packages manually you can fire up Ubuntu Software Center or even good old but slighly more risky Synaptic, browse the 'installed' section and start removing whatever you think you do not need. That can include all the old programs but even programs that are in your current install but you never will use.

I bet it will be an odd 10 or so you want to remove and that might take you a 15 minutes,

Comment: That won't help in finding and selecting the default package line up.